# object of type 'GreedyPlayer' has no len()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

Tengo mi codigo:

```
class GreedyPlayer():
def __init__(self, player=1, board_shape=None, env=None, flatten_action=False):



     if (env is None) and (board_shape is None):
         print("board_shape and env can't be both None")
     if env is None:
         env = ReversiEnv(board_shape=board_shape)
     self.env = env
     self.player = player # player number. 1 o -1
     self.flatten_action = flatten_action
     self.board_shape = self.env.board.shape[0]

def predict(self, board):
    valid_actions = np.argwhere(self.env.get_valid((board, self.player)) == 1)
    if len(valid_actions) == 0:
        print('pass')
        action = self.env.PASS
    else:
        moves_score = []
        for a in valid_actions:
            next_state, _, _, _ = self.env.next_step((board, self.player), a)
            moves_score.append(next_state[0].sum() * self.player)
        best_score = max(moves_score)
        best_actions = valid_actions[np.array(moves_score)==best_score]
        action = best_actions[np.random.randint(len(best_actions))]
    # Implementar
    # Tiene que devoler la acción en la que come más piezas.
    # A igualdad de piezas comidas, samplear uniformemente
    if self.flatten_action:
        return action[0] * self.board_shape + action[1]
    else:
        return action
```

El error  que me da es: object of type 'GreedyPlayer' has no len()

Entiendo que puede ser que deba colocar un `def__len__` para la funcion class GreedyPlayer():
La verdad no se si seria de esta forma.
Me podrían dar alguna idea de esto??

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Para diagnosticar un error es de ayuda conocer el contexto en que se produce (qué línea da el error y desde donde fue llamada). Por eso Python lo imprime junto con el error. ¿puedes poner el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2f257399b1d8> in <module>()
----> 1 arena_stats(DictPolicyPlayer, GreedyPlayer, 4, N=2000)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/boardgame2/env.py in is_index(board, location)
     50     is_index : bool
     51     """
---> 52     if len(location) != 2:
     53         return False
     54     x, y = location

TypeError: object of type 'DictPolicyPlayer' has no len()

Comment: Parece que tu código se integra en algún tipo de _framework_ que espera que le pases un objeto que pueda interpretarse como unas "coordenadas" x,y (location). Aunque quizás admita otro tipo de objeto, no está claro a partir de la información suministrada. ¿Cuál es ese framework que estás usando? ¿O has escrito tú `arena_stats()`? Si es tuyo deberías incluir también su código (por favor edita la pregunta para ello, el código queda casi ilegible en comentarios)